# JAVA - Google maps api recuperar distância da linha

Tags: java, spring-boot

Estou desenvolvendo um app para android que usa a google maps API, está tudo certo com o app o problema está no webservice que lida com as informações recolhidas pelo app, em determinado momento eu crio uma Polyline no app e envio as coordenadas para o WS, eu preciso verificar no WS qual a distância de um ponto qualquer da linha que eu criei por exemplo, suponhamos que a minha linha inicie no ponto `-25.428781,-49.263291` e termine no ponto `-25.431941,-49.261888`, eu preciso saber a distância do ponto `-25.431069,-49.263251` da minha LINHA, não a distância do terceiro ponto ao primeiro e nem do terceiro ponto ao segundo, preciso saber a distância da LINHA. No Android tem uma biblioteca que faz isso a android-maps-utils do próprio google, porém não consegui usá-la em meu WS pois se trata de um pacote `.aar` e estou usando o maven, aceito sugestões de soluções diretamente para o problema como também soluções para adicionar esse `.aar` no meu projeto pois ambas resolveriam o problema. Para simplificar deixo aqui a imagem do mapa:
[image: Rotas]

Preciso saber a distância da linha VERDE, entre o ponto de referência e a rota.

Comment: Isso é uma questão de geometria. Veja [Point-Line Distance--2-Dimensional](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Point-LineDistance2-Dimensional.html) e use a equação 14.

Comment: Sim, já estava até pesquisando como calcular distância de ponto da reta :) o unico problema é utilizar latitudes e longitudes para o calculo, porém como essa funcionalidade está disponível no android pensei ter algo semelhante disponível para uma aplicação java.

Comment: Sobre a edição das tags não concordo que essa duvida seja relacionada a android pois como eu disse, no aplicativo está funcionando normalmente, o problema é no WS que é java(spring boot). Não sei como comunicar essa discordancia portanto postei como comentário.

Comment: Editei agora. Em situações que não concorde com a edição você mesmo pode reverter a edição ou editar a pergunta e colocar as tags que pretender.

Comment: No inicio pensei que a resposta no ramaral não iria me ajudar, porém testei e funcionou perfeitamente. Tive um pouco de trabalho para converter o resultado para metros por usar latitudes e longitudes como referencia, mas deu certinho, obrigado.

Comment: Coloque uma resposta com a sua solução.

Answer (score 1):

Como recomendado pelo [@ramaral](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/2541/ramaral) aqui vai a solução.

Usei como referencia as posições geográficas (latitude e longitude)

Eu tenho então a minha reta que vai de `-25.428781,-49.263291` até `-25.431941,-49.261888` e tenho o ponto que quero saber a distância que é o `-25.431069,-49.263251` 
Apliquei então a fórmula para descobrir a distância de um ponto da reta (Equação 14 - [Point-Line Distance--2-Dimensional](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Point-LineDistance2-Dimensional.html) ) dessa maneira:

```
Double startLat = -25.428781;
Double startLng = -49.263291;

Double endLat = -25.431941;
Double endLng = -49.261888;

Double myLocationLat = -25.431069;
Double myLocationLng = -49.263251;

Double distancia = (((endLat - startLat) * (startLng - myLocationLng)) - ((startLat - myLocationLat) * (endLng - startLng))) / Math.sqrt( (Math.pow( (endLat - startLat), 2) + Math.pow( (endLng - startLng), 2) ) );
```

Porém assim consegui a distância em graus (Que é uma das unidades de medida de latitudes e longitudes). Para conseguir o valor em metros tive que pesquisar um pouco mais e encontrei como converter de graus para kilometros e então para metros dessa forma:

```
( (distancia * 111.325) * 1000)
```

Cada grau de latitude equivale a 111,325 kilometros, depois de multiplicar o resultado da equação por esse valor multipliquei por 1000 para obter o resultado em metros. Nos meus testes a precisão foi de aproximadamente 2 metros, o que no meu caso é o suficiente.